# What can I use to calculate distance?

Tags: electrical-engineering, automotive-engineering, computer-engineering

Please excuse my ignorance in advance, (I'm in cs not EE), I am trying to figure out how can I get the distance from a car to a wall, what form of technology could I use IR sensors, ultrasound, etc.(that is the most cost effective and easy to use), when its all said and done I just want it to send a numerical value of the distance from the car to the wall.

Comment: Ultrasound seems to be in use on quite a lot of systems already on the market, so I'd say go for that.  (If trying something different like IR you should watch out for the effect of direct sunlight, etc.)

Comment: How much money do you have? What's the max and min range you need to cover?

Comment: Can't answer this unless you define the distance you're interested in more clearly. Surface of the car? Centroid of the car? Bubble around the car? Different techniques and technologies may be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of solutions available. You will have to decide a budget and the required accuracy to settle for one.

1) Laser distance sensor - These will give you pretty accurate measurements over a wide range of distances. You can take a look at the product catalog here: https://www.sick.com/us/en/product-portfolio/c/PRODUCT_ROOT

2) Ultrasonic distance sensor - These are way cheaper than laser ones and will give you decent accuracy over a shorter distance. This one from sparkfun will give you a range of about 6 meters: [Ultrasonic Range Finder - LV-MaxSonar-EZ1](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/639)

3) Infrared distance sensor - These are even cheaper but you won't get great accuracy. They work in even lower distance ranges as compared to previous two. Here is a link for your reference: [Infrared Proximity Sensor Long Range - Sharp GP2Y0A02YK0F](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8958)

Everything boils down to what exactly you want - how much accurate, what distance range and how cheap.

Comment: Prices of time of flight lasers has come crashing down, so if you want a close distance measure then these are in many cases cheaper than the others (you can ge one for about a euro or a half euro). But beware there are regulatory reasons for not using them.